# Json.NET: Empty objects after Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I using Json.Net library for serilization.

Here is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var field1 = new Field();
            field1.ExtraFields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();

            var field2 = new Field();
            field1.ExtraFields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();

            var panelRow1 = new PanelRow();
            panelRow1.Fields = new List<Field>();

            var panelRow2 = new PanelRow();
            panelRow2.Fields = new List<Field>();

            var row1 = new Row();
            row1.PanelRows = new List<PanelRow>();
            row1.PanelRows.Add(panelRow1);
            row1.PanelRows.Add(panelRow2);

            var row2 = new Row();
            row2.PanelRows = new List<PanelRow>();
            row2.PanelRows.Add(panelRow1);
            row2.PanelRows.Add(panelRow2);

            var baseForm = new BaseForm();
            baseForm.Rows = new List<Row>();
            baseForm.Rows.Add(row1);
            baseForm.Rows.Add(row2);

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseForm, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class BaseForm
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rows")]
        public IList<Row> Rows { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeRows()
        {
            return Rows.Count != 0;
        }
    }

    class Row
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "panels")]
        public IList<PanelRow> PanelRows { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializePanelRows()
        {
            return PanelRows.Count != 0;
        }
    }

    class PanelRow
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fields")]
        public IList<Field> Fields { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeFields()
        {
            return Fields.Count != 0;
        }
    }

    class Field
    {
        [JsonExtensionData]
        public IDictionary<string, JToken> ExtraFields { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeExtraFields()
        {
            return ExtraFields.Count != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

After serialization I have empty objects in array:

[image]

I this case results must be like this:

```
{}
```

Because we don't have any info in lower element 'Field'.

How can I resolve that problem, Remove empty objects from Json results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did nothing with `field1` and `field2`.... this is your problem....

Comment: if you don't know what is the value of `Field` , then why do you even bother to create `Panels` in the first hand to be empty objects.

Comment: Okay, look now on this code with  not empty `Fields` elements: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/OlshevskyR/b0081e27e460d9717881).

Here i have the same problem: [RESULT](http://img.in6k.com/screens/devenv_2016-01-20_15-45-52.png).

Main goal is: Remove element if they don't have `Field` element.

Comment: About: "...then why do you even bother to create `Panels` in the first hand to be empty objects."

In process the elements from `Field` can be removed. Then i need to remove empty elements in all structure, if exists. I'm actually trying to do it here.